# Controlling Django Admin Model Add Entry based on User

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I control the "Add {{Model}}" button in django admin page based on the user? So that only certain admins can visit /admin/xxx/add/ page.

Answer (score 0):

You can asign add permissions per model in the User model administration interface